# Finding a constant in a joint probability density function

Tags: probability

Given the following joint density function:

\begin{equation}
f (x,y) =
\begin{cases}
 c(x+y)^2& \text{} 0 \le x \le 1, 0 \le y \le 1\\
0  &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

I need to find the value of c. From my answer sheet, I know that the answer is $ \frac 67 $. I cannot get to that answer. I have tried to solve similar problems with other functions, and that worked out fine. This is one of my attempts to solve the problem:

$$\int^1_0\int^1_0 c(x+y)^2 \ dy dx = 1$$
$$\int^1_0 [ c(xy+\frac 12y^2)^2]^1_0\  dx = 1$$
$$\int^1_0 ( c(x \cdot 1 +\frac 12 \cdot 1^2)^2 - c(x \cdot 0 +\frac 12 \cdot 0^2)^2) \ dx = 1$$
$$\int^1_0 ( c(x +\frac 12)^2 - 0) \ dx = 1$$
$$[ ( c(\frac 12 x^2 +\frac 12x)^2) \ ]^1_0 = 1$$
$$ ( c(\frac 12 \cdot 1^2 +\frac 12 \cdot 1)^2 - c(\frac 12 \cdot 0^2 +\frac 12 \cdot 0)^2) \  = 1$$
$$ c \  = 1$$

But as you can see, the answer is wrong. Can anyone help me point out where I am making a mistake? Thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you justify the step from the first equation to the second?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}\int_0^1\int_0^1c(x+y)^2dydx&= c\int_0^1\int_0^1(x^2+2xy+y^2)dydx \\ & =c\int_0^1\left(x^2y+xy^2+\frac{y^3}{3}\right)\Big|_{y=0}^{y=1}dx\\ & =c\int_0^1\left(x^2+x+{1\over 3}\right)dx\\ & =c\left({1\over3}+{1\over 2}+{1\over 3}\right)\overset{!}{=}1\\ &\implies c={6\over 7}\end{align}

Comment: I added some steps to make your solution more explicit. I hope that's alright with you

Comment: @b00nheT Your edit is welcome!!

Comment: Thanks a lot, I see that was quite a bad mistake on my part.